# Using memory stream is throwing out of memory exeption

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a requirement where I need to encrypt file of size 1-2 GB in azure function. In am using PGP core library to encrypt file in memory. The below code is throwing out of memory exception if file size is above 700 MB. Note:- I am using azure function. Scaling up of App service plan didn't help.

I there any alternate of Memory stream that I can use. After encryption , I am uploading file into blob storage.

```
var privateKeyEncoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(_options.PGPKeys.PublicKey));
using Stream privateKeyStream = StringToStreamUtility.GenerateStreamFromString(privateKeyEncoded);
privateKeyStream.Position = 0;

var encryptionKeys = new EncryptionKeys(privateKeyStream);
var pgp = new PGP(encryptionKeys);

//encrypt stream
var encryptStream = new MemoryStream();

await pgp.EncryptStreamAsync(streamToEncrypt, encryptStream );
```

Comment: you could open a writing stream to a _file_ directly?

Comment: Where is the file coming from? Not sure if it's possible with this particular encryption but would it possible to do something like: input file stream -> encryption stream -> output blob stream? If it is possible for the encryption stream to process the data in chunks, it would not matter memory-wise how large the file is.

Comment: A MemoryStream is a `Stream` wrapper over a byte[]` buffer. While you could avoid OOM errors by specifying a capacity in the constructor, storing 2GB in memory before even starting to write it is *very* wasteful. With a real `FileStream` the encrypted bytes would be written out as soon as they were available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MemoryStream is a Stream wrapper over a byte[]` buffer. Every time that buffer is full, a new one with double the size is allocated and the data is copied. This eventually uses double the final buffer size (4GB for a 2GB file) but worse, it results in such memory fragmentation that eventually the memory allocator can't find a new contiguous memory block to allocate. That's when you get an OOM.

While you could avoid OOM errors by specifying a capacity in the constructor, storing 2GB in memory before even starting to write it is very wasteful. With a real FileStream the encrypted bytes would be written out as soon as they were available.

Azure Functions allow temporary storage. This means you can create a temporary file, open a stream on it and use it for encryption.

```
var tempPath=Path.GetTempFileName();
try
{
    using (var outputStream=File.Open(tempPath))
    {

        await pgp.EncryptStreamAsync(streamToEncrypt, outputStream);
        ...
    }
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(tempPath);
}
```

Comment: Path.GetTempFileName() will point to Azure web app file system. Is it good Azure function app practice to use temp location in this case?  Will this not lead to server crash if file size is very large?

Answer (score 3):

`MemoryStream` uses a `byte[]` internally, and any `byte[]` is going to get a bit brittle as it gets around/above 1GiB (although in theory a `byte[]` can be nearly 2 GiB, in reality this isn't a good idea, and is rarely seen).

Frankly, `MemoryStream` simply isn't a good choice here; I'd probably suggest using a temporary file instead, and use a `FileStream`. This doesn't attempt to keep everything in memory at once, and is more reliable at large sizes. Alternatively: avoid ever needing all the data at once completely, by performing the encryption in a pass-thru streaming way.